# Best way to ground a pin when Power switch is closed?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I'm using a Particle Electron micrcontroller and powering it by connecting the battery through a power toggle switch. Since I also have a solar panel connected for battery charging, I need to GND the reset pin of the Electron when my toggle switch is in the off position to prevent it from operating off the solar power.

I am trying to make a circuit that GNDs a pin when my battery is connected. I thought I could connect a NPN transistor to the pin, with the battery line as the Base, but that would have the opposite effect of what I need (grounding it when it should stay open). Do I use a PNP transistor instead? Am I going about this wrong? Is there a simple way I can do this?

Comment: use an dpdt or dpst switch

Comment: For a simple hard-latch solution, change your switch into other type than spst, such as dandavis mentioned.